# Cloning a div but it is not formatted like main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my main `div`

```
<div id="question-con">
                <label for="ques-code">Question Setter:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ques-code" name="ques-code"/>
                <div id="question-toggle" style="display:none;">                        
                    <div id="question-div" style="background-color:#A6A6A6;width: 350px;border: 1px solid greenyellow;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <label>Credit</label>
                        <input type="text" name="credit" class="credit" id="credit_0">
                        <label>No of Setter</label>
                        <input type="text" name="setter">
                        <label>Type</label>
                        <input type="text" name="type" id="type">                             
                        <label for="in-ex">Internal/External</label>
                        <input type="text" name="in-ex" id="">    
                        <p class="remove" style="color:red;float: right;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;" >Remove</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <button id="btn-question" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-right: 5px; display: none;">Add</button>
            </div>
```

In each button click, below function is triggered.I cloned the main div here, but the format of the cloned div is not like the main div.

```
$("#btn-question").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                ++question_count;
                var question_clone = $('#question-div').clone();
                question_clone.attr('id', question_count);
                //question_clone.children().attr('id', "question_" + question_count);
                question_clone.children(".credit").attr('id', "credit_" + question_count);
                $('#question-toggle').append(question_clone);
                $("#" + question_count + " input").val("");
            });
```

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfwV0.png)

What can i do?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dx4eacpo/2/ - it is a styling issue... nothing wrong with the clone operation

Comment: One more point: after cloning you have many not unique ids and it can have influence on the styling and behevior

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass true as parameters to the clone to get its formatting too:

```
$('#question-div').clone(true,true);
```

See the [.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents):

## withDataAndEvents

A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is false.

## deepWithDataAndEvents

A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to false).

---

This will only copy formatting of common classes or inline-styles that are applied to the elements but not to specific rules such as if you have `#someid > a` declared then copying the `a` element somewhere else such as `#otherid a` then it will not work. You need to explicitly define the css rules for them.

Comment: those parameter are for copying data and events how does that impact the format... assuming OP meant UI

Comment: I think data means not just html5 data-* attributes but it means all attributes which includes formatting too...

Comment: I did how ever you suggested me. But it is not working. In jsfiddle in your tems it is working fine. Actually in which part shoud i need to change?

Comment: @RubelDinira Whichever element you're cloning and want to gets its formatting too just pass true params in the clone() method.

Comment: This is incorrect, there are many CSS styles that won't apply if you move a clone out of a specific node. For example, if you have `#a p {color: red}` cloning a p tag that was inside #a and inserting it outside will make that p tag look different. There's no way to guarantee a node will look the same unless you manually copy the style attributes you care about

Comment: @JuanMendes OP was not meant like that. See the OP code, OP is styling with inline css.

Comment: You should clarify that in your answer, right now it looks like you're saying it will copy styles. You could update it to say that it will copy inline styles. Except that a clone does copy the style attribute if it was set from the HTML